# turtlebot+RGBDSLAM possibile or not?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to RGBDSLAM on the turtlebot? I want to achieve autonomous navigation。Anyone did ever tried this before successfully?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48026/turtlebot+rgbdslam-possibile-or-not?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-15**:
No, but I would be interested too

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-11-26**:
can you give me some advice about RGBDSLAM on the turtlebot for navigation?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-27**:
That question is very generic and there is not much information about what you want to achieve. Hard to give advise like this, could you be more specific about your project.

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-11-27**:
RGBDSLAM can be achieved at the same time build environment map and draw kinect trajectory.I wanted to use RGBDSLAM package combined with turtlebot to navigate in unknown environment.

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-11-27**:
But I found turtlebot use of SLAM by Gmapping Gmapping use a particle filter algorithm, I doubt 2D or 3D map is built this way?I can modify this algorithm? Thank you

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-29**:
I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you should consider is the following:
RGB-D Slam implements recording of a volumetric map, but neither localization in it, nor navigation.
Navigation is outside of the scope of RGB-D Slam. So if you have another software for navigating in a Pointcloud, Octomap or a 2D map from the downprojected Octomap, then you can use rgbdslam to create the map. I know 3D navigation for this kind of maps exists for the PR2, but it is based on the laser scanner.

There is also a hack to localize via the recorded landmarks (the visual features) if the program is not shutdown inbetween. There is functionality to save the features and their locations to file, yet not to read them back in. I have currently no incentive to add this functionality.

However, it is possible to write a program that reads the features from the file and does localization with it.

In short: I don't know how to do navigation on a turtlebot based on the kinect alone.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0